# Android rotated views onclick not working

Tags: android, rotation, onclicklistener

First of all, I have read many thread about this, I know it's a common API level issue. Views are getting moved, but the onclick listener boundaries are not.

My application requires min API 10 (2.3.3) and I want to know what is the lowest API version where this problem persist. The android documentation does not provide any information about this, but my guess is API 11 (3.0).

I want to disable animations for versions that does not support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){
// Do something for froyo and above versions
} else{
// I won't support animation for you
}
```